# Intruments Call Tree broken mix of R, C++ and Fortran

Tags: c++, r, macos, fortran, openmx

I am trying to profile a function of OpenMx, an R package containing C++ and Fortran code, for CPU time. My operating system is OS X 10.10. I have read the [section](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Profiling-compiled-code) regarding this topic in the R manual. This section and [this post](http://blog.fellstat.com/?p=337) lead me to try Instruments. Here is what I did

1. Opened Instruments
2. Chose the Time Profiler Template
3. Pressed Record
4. Started my R script using RStudio

I get the following output: [image: Instruments Output]. The command line tool [sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sample.1.html) returns the same output.

The problem is that it looks like  `omxunsafedgemm_` would be called directly from the Main Thread. However, this is a low level Fortran function. It is always called by a C++ function called `omxDGEMM`.  In this example `omxDGEMM` is first called by `omxCallRamExpection` (so almost at the bottom of the call tree). The total time of `omxDGEMM` is 0. Thus, the profiling information is currently useless.

In the original version of the package `omxDGEMM` is defined as inline. I changed this in the hope that it would resolve the issue. This was not the case. `omxunsafedgemm` is called by `omxDGEMM` like that

```
F77_CALL(omxunsafedgemm)(&transa, &transb,
                        &(nrow), &(ncol), &(nmid),
                        &alpha, a->data, &(a->leading), 
                        b->data, &(b->leading),&beta, result->data, &(result->leading));
```

Any ideas how to obtain a sensible profiler output?

Comment: Does nobody have any ideas?

Comment: Which compiler do you use for the C part, and which for the Fortran? I have no clue whatsoever, but maybe the instruments stuff only works fine with the LLVM, while your Fortran code was compiled with gfortran or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is caused by the `-O2` flag of the gfortran compiler, which R uses per default. The `-O2` flag turns on all optimization steps that the `-O1` flag enables and more (see [gcc manual page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc.pdf) 98). One of the optimization flags that the `-O1` flags enables is `-fomit-frame-pointer`. Instruments needs the frame pointers to know the parent of a call frame (see [this talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=412)).

Thus, changing

`FFLAGS = -g -O2 $(LTO)` to

`FFLAGS = -g -O2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer $(LTO)`

in `${R_HOME}/etc/Makeconf` resolves the issue. For me `R_HOME=/Library//Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources`

Simply omitting the `-O2` also solves the issue but makes OpenMx considerably slower (200 vs 30 seconds in my case).

Answer (score 1):

If the OpenMx binary came from the OpenMx website via getOpenMx.R then it would have been compiled with gcc/gfortran.  If it came from CRAN it would have been compiled with the OS X compilers LLVM etc (but it would lack parallel computation because OpenMP is not compatible with LLVM).  So you could try the other binary to see if the tags for profiling are better.  Please let us know which version you were using and whether changing version helped.

Comment: I used the OpenMx version from github. As fortran compiler I used gfortran-4.8. As c++ compiler I used gcc. I think I am in the process of finding a solution. I will answer as soon.