# Profling R,C++,Fortran Mix

Tags: c++, r, fortran, profile

I am on an odyssey trying to profile an R package for CPU time that contains a mix of R, C++ and Fortran code. I have tried lots of things that all failed. Has anybody done this before and was successful? No matter with what OS. I have OS X as native OS and Ubuntu and Windows 7 in a virtual machine. If necessary, I can also natively install any OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac OS X Instruments work fine. However, it is important to make sure that the `-fomit-frame-pointer` is not turned on. For details see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378821/intruments-call-tree-broken-mix-of-r-c-and-fortran) and the accepted answer. Also, it is important to compile the packages on the same machine that will be used for profiling to get the source code and not only the disassembly in Instruments.